# python script stops running on terminal after 1 minute

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

I am facing a problem regarding my python script. I am using Ubuntu on my machine as a second operating system and I have written a python code to output different information regarding some proteins. after giving me ouput for the first protein, it slows down way to much in the middle of the process for the second protein and at some point it wont respond anymore. 
when I type control+c I get this message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testPerf.py", line 185, in <module>
uniqueDict(args.input,args.output)

File "testPerf.py", line 73, in uniqueDict

keyName = '%s_%s' %(hmm[i],cassetteId[i])

File "/home/t/anaconda3/envs/crispr-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py",
line 1071, in __getitem__

result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

File "/home/t/anaconda3/envs/crispr-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes>>/base.py", line 4708, in get_value

s = getattr(series, "_values", series)

File "/home/t/anaconda3/envs/crispr-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 562, in _values
```

The part of the code when It stops is as following :

```
 with open(crisprOutputFile, "r") as file1:
            data = pd.read_csv(file1)
            hmm  = data.HMM
            cassetteId = data.cassette_id
            list1 = data.predicted_label
            i = 0
            while i < len(hmm):
                predictedL = list1[i][7:20]
                predictedL =  predictedL.replace( ')','')
                predictedL =  predictedL.replace( ']','')
                predictedL =  predictedL.replace( "'","")
                predictedL =  predictedL.replace( ',','')
                keyName = '%s_%s' %(hmm[i],cassetteId[i])
                if keyName not in dict1:
                    dict1[keyName] = predictedL
                    i+=1
```

This is piece of code reads content from a file called crisprOutputFile and trys to output some data in a dictionary, pretty easy...
Afterwards this dictionary is combined with some other dictionaries to give the output dictionary that holds data regarding proteins.
PLease help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given snippet, if the `keyName` is found in `dict1`, `i` is not incremented.
If `i` remains unchanged, the current iteration will be same as the previous iteration, so it will become an infinite loop.

If you actually meant to update `i` on each iteration (which makes more sense), lower the integration level of `i+=1` like this

```
with open(crisprOutputFile, "r") as file1:
            data = pd.read_csv(file1)
            hmm  = data.HMM
            cassetteId = data.cassette_id
            list1 = data.predicted_label
            i = 0
            while i < len(hmm):
                predictedL = list1[i][7:20]
                predictedL =  predictedL.replace( ')','')
                predictedL =  predictedL.replace( ']','')
                predictedL =  predictedL.replace( "'","")
                predictedL =  predictedL.replace( ',','')
                keyName = '%s_%s' %(hmm[i],cassetteId[i])
                if keyName not in dict1:
                    dict1[keyName] = predictedL
                i+=1
```

As suggested by @run-out in the comments, I would recommend you to use a `for` loop.

Comment: Or remove the while loop and use a safer for loop. for i in range(len(hmm)):